# jQuery programatically change font family in a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I wanna change the font family for some "elements" in the checkboxlist, I'm trying this code but it doesnt works:

**Method** (atm I'm changing the text color and font family in the code behind but I wanna do it with jQuery):

```
private void bindCheckBoxList()
        {
            using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url).OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach (SPWeb currentWeb in web.Site.AllWebs)
                {
                    string webTitle = currentWeb.Title;

                ListItem myWebItem = new ListItem();
                myWebItem.Text = webTitle;
                myWebItem.Value = currentWeb.Url;
                myWebItem.Attributes.Add("id", "cbBold_" + webTitle);
                myWebItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red; font-weight: bold");
                CbList.Items.Add(myWebItem);

                foreach (SPList currentList in currentWeb.Lists)
                {
                    string listTitle = currentList.Title;

                    ListItem myListItem = new ListItem();
                    myListItem.Text = listTitle;
                    myListItem.Value = web.Url + ";" + currentList.Title;
                    myListItem.Attributes.Add("id", "cb_" + listTitle);

                    CbList.Items.Add(myListItem);

                    if (currentList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
                    {
                        myListItem.Text = listTitle + "(Document Library)";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myListItem.Text = listTitle + "(List)";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CbList" runat="Server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CbList_SelectedIndexChanged" BulletStyle="NotSet" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("[id^=CbBold]").css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed set of font sizes and font families? If you are, it will be easier to add them as helper css classes and then toggle these classes using jquery, instead of inlining all of the styles.

Comment: Nope, I just need to bold all "myWebItem", I'm an absolute beginner for jQuery sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared myWebItem "id" as "cbBold_", alter the id.

```
$("[id^=cbBold_]").css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

Comment: @MarcoC keep the habit of accepting the answer if it resolved your issue.